# Django - sending emails (SMTPAuthenticationError)

Tags: django, smtp

I use:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
```

in my app. Yesterday my app normally sent emails without any errors. Today I get "SMTPAuthenticationError". Below is a part of my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'poczta.interia.pl'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username'
EMAIL_ADRESS = 'email_adress'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

This is my email function:

```
def send_activation_email(self):
    subject = 'SUBJECT'
    message = 'MESSAGE'
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_ADRESS
    to_email = self.email
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        from_email,
        [to_email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

I don't have any idea what is going on. Yesterday it was fine, today not. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you turn on support for less secure diveces?

Comment: It seems that gmail thinks this is suspicious activity.

Comment: I don't use gmail account here...